# javascript optimize multiple reduce and map to extract data from nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I am extracting some data out of an array of nested objects, using two `reduce`es, and `map`, which is working at the moment, but it is a bit ugly. How can this be optimized?

```js
function extractSchools(schools) {
  let schoolData = [];

  if (schools) {
    schoolData = schools.reduce(function(parentdata, chlrn) {
      let childrenlist = chlrn.children;
      let childrendata = [];

      if (childrenlist) {
        childrendata = childrenlist.reduce(function(addrsslist, school) {
          return addrsslist.concat(school.address.map(i => i.school));
        }, []);
      }

      return parentdata.concat(chlrn.parent, childrendata);
    }, []);
  }

  return {
    schoolData
  };
}

const schools = [{
    "parent": "Thomas Jefferson",
    "children": [{
        "address": [{
          "school": "School A"
        }]
      },
      {
        "address": [{
          "school": "School B"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": "Jack Chan",
    "children": [{
      "address": [{
        "school": "School C"
      }]
    }]
  }
];


console.log(extractSchools(schools));
```

How can I optimize this function to get the same results? using one `reduce` instead of two... or some other optimal way of doing it.

Comment: Your code is fine, what is the concern with 2 reduces?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code, I'd be more interested in the *why* of some of the choices in data format. A) Why the keys `parent` and `children`. Should they be `name` and `addresses`? Or is there more nesting going on? B) Why is the address an array and is the label nested in an object with a `school` property? I think the only way you can simplify the data conversion is by altering the data format to better meet your front-end requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `if (childrenlist) {` and use a pre-filter.

```
function extractSchools(schools) {
  let schoolData = [];

  if (schools) {
    schoolData = schools
      .filter(data => data.children)
      .reduce((parentdata, chlrn) => {
        const childrendata = chlrn.children.reduce(
          (addrsslist, school) =>
            addrsslist.concat(school.address.map(i => i.school)),
          []
        );
        return parentdata.concat(chlrn.parent, childrendata);
      }, []);
  }

  return { schoolData };
}

const schools = [
  {
    parent: "Thomas Jefferson",
    children: [
      {
        address: [
          {
            school: "School A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        address: [
          {
            school: "School B"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    parent: "Jack Chan",
    children: [
      {
        address: [
          {
            school: "School C"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(extractSchools(schools));
```

Comment: can you provide a full answer ?

Comment: I hope it's helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the result is little different than what you are expecting, but this will be a more generic way where you will have addresses with respect to school.

```
schools.map(p => {
    return {[p.parent]: p.children.map(c => c.address.map(add => add.school))}
})


[
  {
    "Thomas Jefferson": [
      [
        "School A"
      ],
      [
        "School B"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "Jack Chan": [
      [
        "School C"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```